# Without eval(), can JavaScript be compiled into binaries?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, performance

From everything I have read, it seems the only thing mentioned that prevents JavaScript from being compile-once, run-everywhere (or at least, run-per-browser) is the silly `eval()` statement.  Is there anything else about JavaScript that makes this an impossible feat?

Instead of wasting all this time, on every single computer and every browser, JIT-ting and downloading multiple files of source code, I would love to see a browser run JavaScript using less bytes, using less connections, and with blazing fast, optimized code.

How can this be done?

Comment: You *can* compile code using `eval`, you just need access to an implementation of `eval`. And that's not just theory. Cython, which compiles Python (well, a nearly-perfect superset of Python with extensions to interface with C). And several Lisp implementations compile statically, although I don't know if they put any restrictions upon the use of `eval`.

Comment: Javascript is **interpreted** not _compiled_, but a lot of devs use a _compressor_ in order to reduce the size of the file on the wire. Some compressors (like YUI) refuse to munge the scoped variable names when the code contains an `eval` statement. But if you are confident that your `eval` statement will not be harmed by munging, you can use `window.eval` to circumvent that protection.

Comment: @samshull There are such things as Just-in-Time compilers, which are used by all major engines currently to speed up JavaScript execution significantly, so the JavaScript that you have running on your browser right now may very well be compiled

Comment: @yi-jang, your suggestion relies on the idea that compiled code could be trusted not to cause any number of malicious side effects including (but not limited too) memory leaks and buffer overflows. But there is always Chromium's [NativeClient](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/)

Answer (score 2):

This question is flawed on several levels.

1. If you mean any binary format (say, bytecode), then you'd need *all* the JS implementation out there to man up, get together and settle for a standard. Not gonna happen. And even if, it's not guaranteed that you'd get any, let alone significant, improvements in file size over minified JS. Comparing the size of some .py source file with the size of cached .pyc bytecode files I have at hand shows that at least the bytecode of CPython is usually *larger* than the source files. And the source files aren't even minified!
2. If you mean native executables... well, it's hard to compile JS to native code AOT, especially without building a whole implementation while doing so, but it might be possible in theory. It wouldn't give much performance gains though, as you can't eliminate the dynamicness (at least not statically - a JIT compiler can do much better), so you have to pay for it. It also has numerous downsides that render it wholly worthless:

   1. The resulting binary is platform-specific. So either you'd have to send all possible combinations of binaries (which is wasteful and requires additonal special handling by the browsers) or you'd have to do sniffing and send whatever binary you think might fit - which would screw anyone not willing to give out quite a bit of private information for free (by sending a wrong/totally worthless executable).
   2. You propably lose sandboxing. Native code is for the most part a huge black box. Running it in the browser would also mean the browser would go and run executable code it gets from some untrusted source - an invitation for malware. Unless of course you'd integrate a whole top-of-the-line anti-malware suite into every browser. Do I really need to comment further?
   3. Unless you create a standard for all implementations that allows the compiled JS to access all the builtins etc. of the implementation, or otherwise create some way of sharing code, you end up with lots of redundancy (statically linking a whole JS implementation into the binary). The result will propably be way larger than compressed JS.
   4. You still need some standard interface (unless of course you want to go from `architectures * OSs` to `architectures * OSs * browsers` executables) for the DOM integration.
   5. Not even mentioning that *all* browsers would have to support this. Either in a standard way or each on their own. It has been hard (and long) enough convincing all of them to support most of HTML, CSS and JS *in source form*. Or you'd need to introduce some standard way of detecting support for this.
   6. Also (as already indicated), for dynamic languages, a JIT can perform as well as or better than a static compiler. So it's quite possible that (very impropably, given some of the previous points) you'd save a bit of time on the download (which can already be made quite small using minification, gzipping, caching, etc.) and parsing (which isn't the big performance killer anyway). But the actual run time wouldn't improve significantly either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but I definitely was not implying that we give up all the benefits of a browser as a platform (sandboxing, abstraction from OS/architecture, standards), but just asking if there was a more efficient way to deliver JS from the server, to the client, to the machine's stack.  (hence, my suggestion to have binaries per-browser)  As for bytecode having little size gains over minified JS - that's fine, but I can't imagine the average program's bytecode is larger than its source.

Comment: @Jeff: Well, it'd still be a lot of work with, I'd argue, very little benefit. As for bytecode vs. source size: Depends on the language, the bytecode format and the programming style, but e.g. I don't think I ever saw a CPython bytecode file smaller than the source code. Makes sense, as even the more high-level VMs still need extra instructions to handle temporary values and have generally more low-level operations (e.g. `x.y(z)` can be `push x; get member y; push z onto stack; call with 1 arg;` - much more for complex nested expressions). Each's usually 1-4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really wasting that much time though. JavaScript engines spend far more time *running* the JavaScript than parsing it. Sure in theory you could compile JavaScript into machine code, it would be sort of like embedding the JavaScript engine along with the script itself, like a self-extracting ZIP file or something. I don't see the advantage of this though.